# WPF ContentControl inside another ContentControl not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, caliburn.micro

I have a Window with a ContentControl that I use to simulate a Wizard navigation that's working just fine. In order to refactor some code I have extract a form inside of one of the UserControl of the Wizard that I'am using in another Window in the exactly same way...

The UserControl that I've extract is working fine on the other window (Not the wizard one), but not inside of my UserControl inside of the Wizard... I'm using ContentControl in both situations...

I don't get any error... I've debugged and the constructor is been called in both cases, but inside of the Wizard it doens't appear, just that.

The code from the simple Window is:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Desktop.Views.FilePropertiesViewModel">
  <Grid>
     <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ContentControl x:Name="DocumentPropertyListViewModel" />
     </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

And in the code behind, in the constructor of my Window

```
public DocumentPropertyListViewModel DocumentPropertyListViewModel { get; set; }
public FilePropertiesViewModel(){
   this.DocumentPropertyListViewModel = new DocumentPropertyListViewModel(File.Properties, false);
}
```

The difference, as as said is (as a reference, not a real code):

```
<ContentControl x:Name="Wizard"> <!-- Loading plenty of UserControls>
    <ContentControl x:Name="DocumentPropertyListViewModel" />  <!-- One of the UserControls has this -->
</ContentControl>
```

By the way, I'm using Caliburn.Micro, that's why I'm using ContentControl instead of a normal UserControl reference, I couldn't figured it out how to do the other way...

I'am doing something wrong here?

Comment: So you have CM configured and it works but you have that one control that isn't being found?  Second you are using codebehind and not viewmodels? might want to modify your tags Caliburn != Caliburn.Micro, made by the same person but slightly different.

Comment: The control is found, everything is called properly, it just doens't appear in the usercontrol inside my wizard. I'am using viewmodel, don't have nothing in the codebehind

Comment: Have you used the LogManager before?  I would guess there is a binding issue...

Comment: Yeah, you are right... the view that doens't load in the contentcontrol I don't get any message from the LogManager, the view that work I have a message: Attaching Desktop.Views.DocumentPropertyListView to ViewModels.DocumentPropertyListViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might give this a try...

`<ContentControl x:Name="Wizard">
  <ContentControl cm:View.Model="{Binding DocPropListViewProp}" />
</ContentControl>`

Where `DocPropListViewProp` is a viewmodel property of type DocumentPropertyListViewModel in your main window ***viewmodel***

`And in the code behind, in the constructor of my Window
public DocumentPropertyListViewModel DocumentPropertyListViewModel { get; set; }
public FilePropertiesViewModel(){
   this.DocumentPropertyListViewModel = new DocumentPropertyListViewModel(File.Properties, false);
}`

Still troubled by the statement above with the code fragment that you provided saying you had it in the codebehind, did you mean ViewModel?

Also what container are you using for IoC: MEF, SimpleContainer, etc...? Nothing?

Comment: Thanks man, took me some time to come back to this... I needed to change the property to notify when changed the value too